# Using a Scanner to read a txt.file

Tags: java, arraylist

I am trying to read a .txt file using the built in Scanner class in java 8, however I am getting mixed results with essentially the same lines of code. A little background about my .txt files: they both consist of 1000 line's of different data (One is about a Book and it's features, and the other is about the Patrons). When I go out to print my list however, the Patron.txt file prints out all 1000 lines while my Books.txt only prints out a maximum of 483 lines. Below I showed what line 483 of my .txt file looks like and it looks similar to all the other ones.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class LibManager {
    private ArrayList<Book> bookList = new ArrayList<Book>();
    private ArrayList<Patron> patronList = new ArrayList<Patron>();
    private ArrayList<Loan> loanList = new ArrayList<Loan>();
    private String[] menuOptions;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        LibManager lm = new LibManager();
        lm.execute();
    }

    public LibManager() {
        bookList = readBooks("Resources/books.txt");
        patronList = readPatrons("Resources/patrons.txt");
        loanList = readLoans("Resources/loans.txt");

        menuOptions = new String[] { "Add Book", "Add Patron", "List Books", "List Patrons", "List By Author",
                "List By Year", "Lend Book", "Return Book", "Show Borrower", "Show Borrowed Books", "Remove Book", "Remove Patron",
                "Show Overdue Books", "Exit" };
    }

    private void execute() {

        while (true) {
            int opt = getMenuOption();
            switch (opt) {
            case 1:
                addBook();
                break;
            case 2:
                addPatron();
                break;
            case 3:
                listBooks();
                break;
            case 4:
                listPatrons();
                break;
            case 5:
                listByAuthor();
                break;
            case 6:
                listByYear();
                break;
            case 7:
                lendBookToPatron();
                break;
            case 8:
                returnBook();
                break;
            case 9:
                showBorrowers();
                break;
            case 10:
                showBorrowedBooks();
                break;
            case 11:
                removeBook();
                break;
            case 12:
                removePatron();
                break;
            case 13:
                showOverdueBooks();
                break;
            case 14:
                exitProgram();
                break;
            default:
                System.out.println("No such option");
            }
        }

    }

    private int getMenuOption() {

        System.out.println("Select one of the following options");
        for (int i = 0; i < menuOptions.length; i++) {
            System.out.println("\t" + (i + 1) + ". " + menuOptions[i]);
        }

        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        int choice = s.nextInt();

        return choice;
    }

    /* MAKE NO CHANGES ABOVE THIS LINE */
    /* COMPLETE ALL THE CODE STUBS BELOW */

    private void exitProgram() {
        System.out.println("Exiting..");
        System.exit(0);
    }

    private ArrayList<Book> readBooks(String filename) {
         List lines = new ArrayList();
            Scanner s = null;
            File infile = new File(filename);
            try {
                s = new Scanner(infile);
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            while (s.hasNext()) 
                lines.add(s.nextLine().replaceAll("\\s+",""));
            return (ArrayList<Book>) lines;
    }

    private ArrayList<Patron> readPatrons(String filename) {
        List lines = new ArrayList();
        Scanner s = null;
        File infile = new File(filename);
        try {
            s = new Scanner(infile);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        while (s.hasNext()) 
            lines.add(s.nextLine());
        return (ArrayList<Patron>) lines;
    }
```

Results for readBooks (the last 5 lines):
Expected B999.

```
B48;Choke;ChuckPalahniuk;1897
B480;Voss;PatrickWhite;1953
B481;TheMidwichCuckoos;JohnWyndham;1864
B482;BlueNoon;GeorgesBataille;1781
B483;HomoFaber;MaxFri
```

Results for readPatrons (the last 5 lines):
Expected P999

```
P995    MURILLO
P996    LUTZ
P997    DUARTE
P998    KIDD
P999    KEY
```

Looking at my Books.txt file, there is nothing wrong with line 483

```
B483    ;   Homo Faber  ;   Max Frisch      ;   1955
```

---

UPDATE: The problem still persists, but I am allowed to add another book on top of the list to get it past the 483 mark.

---

Used to print out the book list.

```
private void listBooks() {
        for(int i=0;i<bookList.size();i++){
            System.out.println(bookList.get(i));
        }
    }
```

Comment: `B483;HomoFaber;MaxFri` shows that casting of that `line` String to `Book` object has failed and it bailed out.

Comment: What happens when you remove the line 483 ?

Comment: You should be using hasNextLine() and nextLine() methods. And a general comment, write one common method for reading files.

Comment: @XavierBouclet when line 483 is deleted, 484 does the same exact thing.

Comment: Could you add the showBorrowedBooks method? I see nothing wrong with your code.

Comment: @XavierBouclet There is no code for that method as of yet, I'm currently going down the order. So i've done the first four methods.

Comment: So whitch method does the output ? Could you add the code?

Comment: @XavierBouclet Added.

Comment: I wonder if the replaceAll is the problem. Could you try to remove it and see what happens

Comment: @XavierBouclet I removed that part and it still stops at line 483. Do you think there is something wrong with my readBooks function or even my .txt file?

Comment: Can swap `while (s.hasNext()) ` for  `while (s.hasNextLine())` as @geekprogrammer noted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I some how fixed my problem on my own. So I'm going to post what I did. I imported FileInputStream and added it to my readBooks method. However, I am still confused why this worked with FileInputStream and not my original method?

```
private ArrayList<Book> readBooks(String filename) {
        ArrayList<Book> lines = new ArrayList<>();
        Scanner s = null;
        File infile = new File(filename);
        try{
            FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(infile);
            s = new Scanner(fis);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        while(s.hasNextLine())
            lines.add(new Book(s.nextLine()));
        return lines;
```

Comment: Your new method doesn't have the replaceAll